# Javascript click event triggers print in console on C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a table of events that has three different odds: OddsFirsteTeam, OddsDraw, OddsSecondTeam.

[image]

> When an odd from an event is clicked in ‘Preview Mode’ it prints
> in the console  ‘A B C’ where A is the EventID of the event, B is the
> type of the ODD (one of the 3 types - OddsForFirstTeam/ OddsForDraw/
> OddsForSecondTeam) and C is the Odd Value (3.25 for example)

Here is my view:

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Name
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.OddsForFirstTeam
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.OddsForDraw
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.OddsForSecondTeam
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.StartDate
            </td>

        </tr>
```

Javascript works and I get the value of each of the td's.

```
$(document).on("click", "td:nth-child(2)", function () {
    let oddValue = $(this).text().trim();
    let id = $(this).siblings().first().find(':input').val();
    let nameofOddProp = $(this).parent().parent().siblings().first().find('th:nth-child(2)').text().trim();
    console.log(`EventId: ${id}, name: ${nameofOddProp}, OddValue: ${oddValue}`);
});

$(document).on("click", "td:nth-child(3)", function () {
    let oddValue = $(this).text().trim();
    let id = $(this).siblings().first().find(':input').val();
    let nameofOddProp = $(this).parent().parent().siblings().first().find('th:nth-child(3)').text().trim();
    console.log(`EventId: ${id}, name: ${nameofOddProp}, OddValue: ${oddValue}`);
});

$(document).on("click", "td:nth-child(4)", function () {
    let oddValue = $(this).text().trim();
    let id = $(this).siblings().first().find(':input').val();
    let nameofOddProp = $(this).parent().parent().siblings().first().find('th:nth-child(4)').text().trim();
    console.log(`EventId: ${id}, name: ${nameofOddProp}, OddValue: ${oddValue}`);
});
```

I got all the info I need, I just need to save it to C# code and execute it on the console.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  What's the question?  And can you please spell out more explicitly exactly how this relates to C#?  Browsers have consoles (console.log) and C# has a terminal console (Console.WriteLine) -- not sure at all what you're referring to.

Comment: Can you clarify _"save it to C# code..."_ - re: you're outputting to the browser console via javascript (client side), and __?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to see your console log? Press F12 and look at the bottom.